# Why I get when call code from function?

Tags: autohotkey

This the code I am trying to call from a function.

it works fine without problem if I use by itself

```
#3::
FileRead, OutputVar, C:\temp\test.txt
msgbox %OutputVar%
#SingleInstance, force

Gui, Color, White
Gui, -caption +toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, font, s30 bold, Arial
Gui, add, text, vTX cRed TransColor, %OutputVar%
Gui, Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth-1500 " y" A_ScreenHeight-900 ,TRANS-WIN
WinSet, TransColor, White, TRANS-WIN
return
```

when I call put that in function and call it from there I get error below.

```
:*:11::
Run calc.exe
numcodee()
return

numcodee()
{
FileRead, OutputVar, C:\temp\test.txt
msgbox %OutputVar%
#SingleInstance, force

Gui, Color, White
Gui, -caption +toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, font, s30 bold, Arial
Gui, add, text, vTX cRed TransColor, %OutputVar%
Gui, Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth-1500 " y" A_ScreenHeight-900 ,TRANS-WIN
WinSet, TransColor, White, TRANS-WIN
}
```

**Error** when call it from function
[image]

Comment: Any Control that has a variable attached to it must be static or global. This is fixed by simply adding global VarName in your function. (In your case, global TX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI requires its variables remain in scope for longer than you are allowing. Its been a while since I did anything major with AKH but I would guess is your OutputVar which is causing the error. The way to fix this is simply to move the data from the function, and list it somewhere above in the file)

The thing to keep in mind is that once your function ends, all the variables declared inside it will fall out of scope and you wont be able to use them, the GUI is concerned something it will need will fall out from under it.

Comment: I was able to fix it by declaring global variable and destroying gui. `global 
FileRead, OutputVar, C:\temp\test.txt 
Gui, Destroy`